# Have you had an iOS app be rejected because of a mismatch in Xcode and SDK releases?

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk, app-store-connect

My app has a number of issues when compiled using SDK 7.0, so for the time being I'm setting my "Base SDK" to 6.1 (from Xcode4) in Xcode5 for production builds.

I wasn't able to find anything that said this would be an issue, but with the amount of time it takes to get an app approved or rejected, I'm slightly paranoid.

I was wondering if anyone has experienced a rejection due to a mismatch in Xcode and SDK release cycles like this?

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about App Store compliance and interaction, not a coding issue. Please see [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic for Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/175701)

Comment: I don't see why that would be an issue, as long as you're following the guidelines.

Comment: @PaulG My concern is mostly based on the fact that I wasn't able to find any official documentation for setting up multiple Base SDKs in Xcode. A lot of people on SO flatly reject this configuration as unsupported, even with the directory that needs to be modified being called "SDKs" (plural) and the UI support for choosing them.

Comment: I've never heard of this. However, hacking Xcode to use older SDKs (as is necessary to use 4.6 with XC 5) would be an unsupported configuration, so I'm not surprised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with setting the Base SDK to a lower value than the version that is included with XCode. That setting is there so you can build code that is backwards compatible with previous iOS versions. I have submitted apps using exactly this functionality in the past that were not rejected.